# Cannot access child static property from parent static method in PHP

Tags: php, static, global-state

I am having some problem in my PHP code. I have three classes named as

1. DatabaseObject
2. File
3. user_picture

And their inheritance tree from parent to child class is **DatabseObect->File->user_picture**. Here in **user_picture** I have a static property $table_name that I am using to know database table name for each class and have some common database functions in **DatabaseObject** class. Code for a function I am using is here

**Code For DatabaseObject Class**

```
public static function find_by_field($field="", $value="")
{
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name." WHERE {$field} = '".$value."'"); //Line 52
    if(empty($result_array))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $object = static::instantiate(array_shift($result_array));
        return $object;
    }
}
```

**Code For File Class**

```
public $errors=array();

public $file_before_upload; // General file tyoe that has been uploaded from the form
public $id = 0;
public $size;
public $file_name;
public $file_type;
public $user_id;

protected $temp_path;
//protected static $upload_dir="";

protected $upload_errors = array(
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK               => "No errors.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => "Partial upload.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      => "No file.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "No temporary directory.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => "File upload stopped by extension."
);
public static function get_file_by_user($id = 0){
       return DatabaseObject::find_by_field("user_id",$id); //Line 164
    }
```

**Code for user_picture Class**

```
protected static $table_name = "user_images";
    protected static $db_fields = array('id','file_name','file_type','size','user_id');

    public static $upload_dir ="uploads".DS."user_img";
    protected static $file_upload_limit = 15;


    public static function get_image_by_user($id = 0)
    {
        return File::get_file_by_user($id);  //Line 45
    }
```

And From where I am calling upper function in **user_picture** is

```
$user_image = user_picture::get_image_by_user($session->user_id);

$user_picture_path="";

if(!$user_image)
{
    $user_picture_path = $user_image::upload_dir.DS."default.png";
}
else{
    $user_picture_path = $user_image::file_path(); //Line 28
}
```

this code gives me the following error

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: DatabaseObject::$table_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\includes\database\DatabaseObject.php:52
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\includes\general\File.php(164): DatabaseObject::find_by_field('user_id', '29')
>
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\includes\user\user_picture.php(45): File::get_file_by_user('29')
>
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\public\admin\layouts\admin\header\Navigation.php(28): user_picture::get_image_by_user('29')
>
> 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\public\admin\layouts\admin\header\admin_header.php(21): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
>
> 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\public\admin\add_page_category.php(44): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
>
> 5 {main}
>     thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-management\includes\database\DatabaseObject.php** on line **52**

Please if anybody can help!

Thanks,

Comment: What is in your `File.php` on line 77?

Comment: How is `$user_image` declared? what are the other properties for `UserImage`? *we need more info*

Comment: Now Please have a look I have updated it with properties and lines of errors in code comments. Thanks.

Comment: @JakubKrawczyk As for **User_Image** the static function **get_user_by_image($id)** return a object.

Comment: Instead of using static methods/variables to implement procedural code, you should attempt applying object oriented paradigm. You should also avoid breaking the encapsulation, avoid violating LSP and stop mixing the SQL and business logic.

Comment: @tereško There is not an mixing of SQL with business model as DatabaseObject is acting as DataLayer and all database related methods are implemented in it. As i have to perform some operation without using objects them here static methods come in handy. And For static Variables They are very helpful in keeping Refactoring and code reuse-ability. As for OOP Paradigm shouldn't we try and avoid repeating code for same work and Mostof libraries or builtin classes do like as in inheritance e.g: **Object->ClassA->ClassB** .  Hey, Please correct where I am wrong.

Comment: @kirito70 there is mixing, because in your code the `DatabaseObject` is a superclass for `User_Picture` class. You can't separate layers, when you are abusing inheritance. Static variables are basically namespaced-globals. How exactly would global variables in your code improve the reusability? And, stop abusing inheritance and learn to use composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `self` instead of `Database::` and `File::`

```
public static function get_image_by_user($id = 0)
{
    return self::get_file_by_user($id);  //Line 45
}

public static function get_file_by_user($id = 0){
   return self::find_by_field("user_id",$id); //Line 164
}
```

---

Working example :

```
class A {
    static public function foo() {
        var_dump(static::$bar);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static protected $bar = "12";

    static public function zoo(){
        self::foo();
    }
}

B::zoo();
```

Not working example :

```
class A {
    static public function foo() {
        var_dump(static::$bar);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static protected $bar = "12";

    static public function zoo(){
        A::foo();
    }
}

B::zoo();
```

Comment: Sorry! but i was returning value it get omitted by mistake during pasting.

Comment: **DatabaseObject** must consider **$table_name** from **user_picture** class and use it to access data from that database table as i am using **static** keyword, but it is considering   its own static property that it does not have.

Comment: No its there and for insert static keyword works. But, here it is not working

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. And can you kindly give me a hint about the issue.!

Comment: Yes, it was a question. I couldn't understand the reason about this.

Comment: @kirito70 I think calling `AClass::method()` doesn't refers to the inherited static object (just to a static object without references) but `self::` does.

Comment: Ok, I got some idea. Thanks for time. It was great help.